# Versión de PrimeNG

Tags: primeng

¿Qué comando necesito ejecutar para conocer la versión de PrimeNG que estoy utilizando?
O sea quisiera saber si hay algo como `ng version` pero para PrimeNG
gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asumo que ya viste el *package.json*.

Comandos que te pueden ayudar serían.

GitBash

```
npm list | grep <package name>
```

Windows:

```
npm list | find <package name>
```

PowerShell:

```
npm list | sls <package name>
```

[Help](https://peaku.co/es/preguntas/2957-encuentre-la-version-de-un-paquete-npm-instalado)